# Do the PHP output buffers record and hold only echoed things inside php, or echoed things AND html code written outside of php tags?

Tags: php, output, overwrite, output-buffering

And could I activate output buffers during all my PHP code running, then search and replace things in the entire page like the title or meta description later then when I wrote them in the code ? My code is written after the head and it got pretty complex...

Else do you have solutions ?

Comment: What have you tried? Your best bet is to your use: Output Control Functions: http://www.php.net/manual/pl/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds all the page data being sent to the client, whether it's written as literal HTML or with `echo`.